# Is there a way to figure out the specific statement that is true in an or statement?

Tags: python, if-statement, pyautogui

I have created a bot for the aim trainer test on humanbenchmark.com and I am trying to improve its speed. Currently, I have defined a function that takes a screenshot of the screen, and then scans for the target image and clicks there. However, in order to determine where the target is efficiently, I need to check the color of three different pixels, and see if they are different from the background color. When doing this, I have 3 different if statements, and I was wondering if it was possible to combine the if statements into 1 if statement with 2 or statements. There might be a more efficient way to do this entirely, but this is the best I could come up with. The code is a bit hard to read, because I tried to define the function for general use, and not just this specific use, but it's not terrible.

```
def scan(colors, width, height, start_x=66, start_y=231, stop_x=1900, stop_y=838):
    im = auto.screenshot('C:\\Windows\\Temp\\screenshot.png')
    coordinates = []
    additive = round((height / 2), 0)
    x_range = stop_x - start_x
    y_range = stop_y - start_y
    for x in range(0, math.ceil((x_range / width))):
        for y in range(0, math.ceil((y_range / height))):
            pixel_1 = im.getpixel((((width * x) + start_x), (start_y + (height * y))))
            pixel_2 = im.getpixel((((width * x) + start_x), (start_y + (height * (y + 1)))))
            pixel_3 = im.getpixel((((width * x) + start_x), (additive + start_y + (height * y))))
            for i in range(0, len(colors)):
                if pixel_1 == colors[i]:
                    location_x = (width * x) + start_x
                    location_y = (height * y) + start_y
                    coordinates.append(location_x)
                    coordinates.append(location_y)
                    break
                if pixel_2 == colors[i]:
                    location_x = (width * x) + start_x
                    location_y = (height * (y + 1)) + start_y
                    coordinates.append(location_x)
                    coordinates.append(location_y)
                    break
                if pixel_3 == colors[i]:
                    location_x = (width * x) + start_x
                    location_y = (height * y) + start_y + additive
                    coordinates.append(location_x)
                    coordinates.append(location_y)
                    break
    return coordinates[0], coordinates[1]
```

Here's what I want to be able to do.

```
def scan(colors, width, height, start_x=66, start_y=231, stop_x=1900, stop_y=838):
    im = auto.screenshot('C:\\Windows\\Temp\\screenshot.png')
    coordinates = []
    additive = round((height / 2), 0)
    x_range = stop_x - start_x
    y_range = stop_y - start_y
    for x in range(0, math.ceil((x_range / width))):
        for y in range(0, math.ceil((y_range / height))):
            pixel_1 = im.getpixel((((width * x) + start_x), (start_y + (height * y))))
            pixel_2 = im.getpixel((((width * x) + start_x), (start_y + (height * (y + 1)))))
            pixel_3 = im.getpixel((((width * x) + start_x), (additive + start_y + (height * y))))
            for i in range(0, len(colors)):
                if pixel_1 == colors[i] or pixel_2 == colors[i] or pixel_3 == colors[i]:
...
    return coordinates[0], coordinates[1]
```

There are a couple edge cases where this program doesn't work, but they are uncommon enough that it isn't worth the loss in efficiency to account for them.

I tried having it as one if statement, but I wasn't able to figure out a way to tell which of the statements was true. I tried decreasing it to just checking one or two pixels as well, but this led to too many cases where it didn't detect the target and the program broke. I'm hoping to speed the program up, as currently each call of the function takes ~200ms.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "efficiency"?  In the original code sample you have a `break` at the end of each `if` block, so it will enter at most one `if` block per loop iteration, so from an execution speed standpoint, I don't think there is any efficiency loss.  Do you mean from a code layout/"prettiness" standpoint?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the walrus operator to assign a variable while testing

```
pixel = None
if (pixel_1 == colors[i] and (pixel := 1)) or (pixel_2 == colors[i] and (pixel := 2))  or (pixel_3 == colors[i] and (pixel := 3)):
    location_x = (width * x) + start_x
    if pixel == 1:
        location_y = (height * y) + start_y
    elif pixel == 2:
        location_y = (height * (y + 1)) + start_y
    else:
        location_y = (height * y) + start_y + additive
    coordinates.append(location_x)
    coordinates.append(location_y)
    break
```